# Monodromy of differential equations

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-operators

Let $D$ an ordinary differential equation (let's assume $D$ only has regular singularities). Suppose $D$ = $D_0$$\partial$, where $\partial$ is $q\frac{d}{dq}$ My question is: Does there exist any relation between the monodromy of $D$ and that of $D_0$? If so, Is it sufficient to know the monodromy of $D_0$ in order to know the monodromy of $D$?

Thanks in advance for your cooperation